# How to insert an option using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple video tag that I would like to change the option on from autoplay to pause and back and forth.

HTML:

```
<video webkit-playsinline {{playa}} loop ng-src="{{keeper}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0px solid red;border-radius:100px;z-index:1;">
</video>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.play = function () {
$scope.playa=autoplay;
}

$scope.pause = function () {
$scope.playa=pause;
}
```

I would have a two buttons, pause and play, to execute each function
The above code does not work and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated!

ERROR from web console:

```
Error: autoplay is not defined
@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/js/controllers.js:661:3
invoke@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13282:14
instantiate@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13290:27
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17846:18
self.appendViewElement@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:52338:24
ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.render@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50456:29
ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.init@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50376:11
self.render@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:52198:5
self.register@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:52156:5
updateView@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57577:11
.compile/</<@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57554:11
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24997:15
transitionTo/$state.transition<@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:44841:11
processQueue@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23399:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23415:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24678:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24489:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24783:13
timeout/timeoutId<@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26550:25
completeOutstandingRequest@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14226:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@file:///Users/MehdiNathani/Desktop/Celebrity%20Fitness/Celebrity%20Fitness/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14498:7
```

Comment: Don't clarify things in comments. Update the question with any clarifications you have.

Comment: Are `autoplay` and `pause` supposed to be strings in your controller?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] . if the code above is used then you would see errors thrown that `pause` and `autoplay` are undefined

Comment: @Soviut no not exactly...they should actually just be code...but I'm not sure how to store code or if that is even possible

Comment: @charlietfl I thought it was simple enough to not require an example...can you think of a workaround for this problem...i just need to toggle between autoplay and pause by the user clicking

Comment: well for starters are you seeing errors? The variables shown are undefined. Also there are numerous sandbox sites where putting examples together is not time consuming or difficult...plunker, jsfiddle, codepen etc

Comment: Posted the error...I will look into those websites and try to put together a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible, but in any case the error is that autoplay and pause are not defined. Now you are assigning to playa the value of autoplay, not the string autoplay.
Maybe you would:

$scope.playa = 'autoplay';

and
$scope.playa = 'pause';